# How to export expandable rows to csv using MUIDataTable

Tags: material-ui, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, mui-datatable

I would like to export all data to a csv file using MUIDataTable:

1. data contained in const columns (so far I only get to export this data)
2. data contained in const rows (missing in csv file)

I have tried with these settings in options but only get to export the data from rows that are NOT expandable. It seems like I am not able to override the default settings of the download function already built-in MUIDataTable.

Is there any other way I can do this?

This is the doc I am using but I dont find the right solution: https://bestofreactjs.com/repo/gregnb-mui-datatables-react-table-grid

```
expandableRows: true,
download: true,
downloadOptions: {
  filename: "tableDownload.csv",
  separator: ";",
  filterOptions: { useDisplayedColumnsOnly: true },
  useDisplayedRowsOnly: true,
}
```

---

```
import React from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";


const ExpandableRowTable = (props) => {
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Name",
    },
    {
      name: "Title",
    },
    {
      name: "Location",
    },
    {
      name: "Age",
    },
    {
      name: "Salary",
    },
  ];
  const data = [
    ["Gabby George", "Business Analyst", "Minneapolis", 30, 100000],
    ["Niklas Svensson", "Business Consultant", "Dallas", 55, 200000],
    ["Jaden Collins", "Attorney", "Santa Ana", 27, 500000],
    ["Franky Rees", "Business Analyst", "St. Petersburg", 22, 50000],
    ["Aaren Rose", "Business Consultant", "Toledo", 28, 75000],
    ["Blake Duncan", "Business Management Analyst", "San Diego", 65, 94000],
    ["Frankie Parry", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Jacksonville", 71, 210000],
    ["Lane Wilson", "Commercial Specialist", "Omaha", 19, 65000],
    ["Robin Duncan", "Business Analyst", "Los Angeles", 20, 77000],
    ["Mel Brooks", "Business Consultant", "Oklahoma City", 37, 135000],
    ["Harper White", "Attorney", "Pittsburgh", 52, 420000],
    ["Kris Humphrey", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Laredo", 30, 150000],
    ["Frankie Long", "Industrial Analyst", "Austin", 31, 170000],
    ["Brynn Robbins", "Business Analyst", "Norfolk", 22, 90000],
    ["Justice Mann", "Business Consultant", "Chicago", 24, 133000],
    ["Addison Navarro", "Business Management Analyst", "New York", 50, 295000],
    ["Jesse Welch", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Seattle", 28, 200000],
    ["Eli Mejia", "Commercial Specialist", "Long Beach", 65, 400000],
    ["Gene Leblanc", "Industrial Analyst", "Hartford", 34, 110000],
    ["Danny Leon", "Computer Scientist", "Newark", 60, 220000],
    ["Lane Lee", "Corporate Counselor", "Cincinnati", 52, 180000],
    ["Jesse Hall", "Business Analyst", "Baltimore", 44, 99000],
    ["Danni Hudson", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Tampa", 37, 90000],
    ["Terry Macdonald", "Commercial Specialist", "Miami", 39, 140000],
    ["Justice Mccarthy", "Attorney", "Tucson", 26, 330000],
    ["Silver Carey", "Computer Scientist", "Memphis", 47, 250000],
    ["Franky Miles", "Industrial Analyst", "Buffalo", 49, 190000],
    ["Glen Nixon", "Corporate Counselor", "Arlington", 44, 80000],
    [
      "Gabby Strickland",
      "Business Process Consultant",
      "Scottsdale",
      26,
      45000,
    ],
    ["Mason Ray", "Computer Scientist", "San Francisco", 39, 142000],
  ];

  function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
    return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
  }

  const rows = [
    createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  ];

  const options = {
    filter: true,
    onFilterChange: (changedColumn, filterList) => {
      console.log(changedColumn, filterList);
    },
    selectableRows: "single",
    filterType: "dropdown",
    responsive: "scrollMaxHeight",
    rowsPerPage: 10,
    expandableRows: true,
    download: true,
    downloadOptions: {
      filename: "tableDownload.csv",
      separator: ";",
      filterOptions: { useDisplayedColumnsOnly: false },
      useDisplayedRowsOnly: false,
    },
    renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
      console.log(rowData, rowMeta);
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan={6}>
              <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                <Table style={{ minWidth: "650" }} aria-label="simple table">
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row) => (
                      <TableRow key={row.name}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                          {row.name}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </TableContainer>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    },
    page: 1,
  };

  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={"ACME Employee list"}
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};

export default ExpandableRowTable;
```